# How to make paired comparison for elements in one list

Tags: r, list, for-loop, iteration, comparison

I have a list with four models as you could see and I am supposed to compare:

[image]

1. the first one with the second one
2. the second one with the third one
3. the third one with the last

Thus I have proceeded with the following code, by creating a list for paired comparison:

```
comparison = vector('list', length = 3)
list_comparison = list(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(3,4)) 

for (i in list_comparison){
  comparison[i] = summary(compareFit(models[[i[1]]], models[[i[2]]]))
}
```

But the way I cannot stop the loop to remake twice the last comparison (3 vs 4) and in the list, I find twice with the same results.

```
length(comparison)
[1] 4
```

How is that possible? How could be the index improved? Could you suggest some alternatives if there is no solution?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to loop over the sequence i.e. `for(i in seq_along(list_comparison))`, and then use `comparison[[i]] <-summary(compareFit(models[[list_comparison[[i]][1]]], models[[list_comparison[[i]][2]]]))`

Comment: Great. It worked very nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just that the `comparison` assignment index is based on the value of the `list_comparison` which is a vector.  Instead, loop over the sequence of the list, thus the output can be assigned to each element of the initiated list 'comparison'

```
for(i in seq_along(list_comparison))
{
tmp <- list_comparison[[i]]
comparison[[i]] <- summary(compareFit(models[[tmp[1]]], 
         models[[tmp[2]]]))
}
```

---

Instead of initiating a `list` and assign, we could also loop over the `list` directly with `lapply`

```
comparison <- lapply(list_comparison, function(x)
                summary(compareFit(models[[x[1]]],
                          models[[x[2]]]))
        )
```